# PyTorch Tensor 使用時のエラー

Tags: python, pytorch

[PyTorch 1.1 : Getting Started : サンプルによる PyTorch の学習 – PyTorch](http://torch.classcat.com/2019/06/25/pytorch-1-1-getting-started-pytorch-with-examples/)

上記サイトのコードを参考に、質問に載せたコードを実行するとエラーが出てきて困っております。

**実行環境**
python3.7.6
pytorch1.3.1
numpy1.17.4

gpu:GeForce GTX 1660 Ti
Cuda:10.1
Cudnn:7.6.5

---

**実行したコード**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import torch

dtype = torch.float
device = torch.device("cpu")
dtype = torch.device("cuda:0") # Uncomment this to run on GPU
print("dtype:", dtype)

# N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
# H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

# Create random input and output data
x = torch.randn(N, D_in, device=device, dtype=dtype)
y = torch.randn(N, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)

# Randomly initialize weights
w1 = torch.randn(D_in, H, device=device, dtype=dtype)
w2 = torch.randn(H, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)

learning_rate = 1e-6
for t in range(500):
    # Forward pass: compute predicted y
    h = x.mm(w1)
    h_relu = h.clamp(min=0)
    y_pred = h_relu.mm(w2)

    # Compute and print loss
    loss = (y_pred - y).pow(2).sum().item()
    print(t, loss)

    # Backprop to compute gradients of w1 and w2 with respect to loss
    grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y)
    grad_w2 = h_relu.t().mm(grad_y_pred)
    grad_h_relu = grad_y_pred.mm(w2.t())
    grad_h = grad_h_relu.clone()
    grad_h[h < 0] = 0
    grad_w1 = x.t().mm(grad_h)

    # Update weights using gradient descent
    w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
    w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
dtype: cuda:0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 119, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 39, in debug
    run()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\U\.conda\envs\env\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\U\.conda\envs\env\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\U\.conda\envs\env\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\exam\tensor.py", line 16, in <module>
    x = torch.randn(N, D_in, device=device, dtype=dtype)
TypeError: randn() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (int, int, dtype=torch.device, device=torch.device), but expected one of:
 * (tuple of ints size, tuple of names names, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
 * (tuple of ints size, torch.Generator generator, tuple of names names, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
 * (tuple of ints size, torch.Generator generator, Tensor out, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
 * (tuple of ints size, Tensor out, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
```

Comment: `dtype = torch.device("cuda:0")` としてしまっているのが原因でしょう。記事では `device = torch.device("cuda:0")` となっていますね。

Comment: 指摘箇所を訂正した所、正しく動作しました。
何かの拍子で誤って書き換えてしまった様です。
指摘して頂いたmetropolis様、並びに質問を見やすく訂正して頂いたcubick様
有難う御座いました。

Answer (score 1):

`dtype = torch.device("cuda:0")` としてしまっているのが原因でしょう。
記事では `device = torch.device("cuda:0")` となっていますね。

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62071/pytorch-tensor-%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e6%99%82%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc#comment67722_62071) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*